# SVG text displaying differently on Firefox from Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I have a svg tag in my HTML. A series of texts have to be displayed on top of the image. The HTML is given below:

```
  <svg version="1.1" id='couponSVG'
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 129.5 187.2" enable-background="new 0 0 129.5 187.2" xml:space="preserve">
      <path fill="#3399ff" id='ticketPath'
          d="16.6V4.3H5.2v12.3c..."/>
      <text x="65" y="20">
          <tspan font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" font-size="8px" text-anchor="middle">Next available ticket</tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="65" y="48">
          <tspan font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle" id="queueNameSVG"></tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="64" y="58">
          <tspan font-size="8px" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle" id="ticketDateSVG"></tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="66" y="122">
          <tspan font-size="64px" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle" id="currentNumberSVG"></tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="66" y="155">
          <tspan class='btn btn-link' font-size="10px" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle" id="showQueueInfo">info / details</tspan>
      </text>
  </svg>
```

Everything inside the text tags should appear on top of the image. This is working correctly on Chrome, but not on Firefox. On Firefox, the entire text contents are going out of the image frame. Does anyone know why this could happen?

Comment: Would you mind throwing the code into a runnable web snippet through stackoverflow, jsfiddle, or codepen? It just makes the process a bit faster and typically gets more people to contribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `xml:space="preserve"` in your `<svg>` tag.

Also, you don't need the `x`, `y` or `enable-background` attributes, but they are unrelated to your problem.